# finding whether the directories are latest in perforce

Tags: linux, perforce

I would like to use a command in script - which can find whether the current directory has all changes from perforce syncd.

I know if it is my workspace I can easily do p4 sync which would get all latest files. But i would not want to sync, I just want to check - that's all !

Answer (score 4):

From `p4 sync` [documentation](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/sync.html):

```
-n Display the results of the sync without actually performing the sync.
```

P.S. You do know how to use Google, right? It's the second hit to [this query](https://www.google.com?q=perforce%20check%20directory%20up%20to%20date).

Comment: Thanks for the reply !! ... Though I read p4 help commands, did google search - but used wrong string .... Anyway it is my mistake, sorry.

Comment: But this is not what I am looking for ! It shows results for entire repository instead of a specific directory.... Yeah I can do some grep or something but it would be better to know if there is an option/command that can do it straight forward

Comment: You can scope the command with a path argument, e.g. <code>p4 sync -n ...</code> will work on the current directory recursively.

Comment: new to p4 ! so wrongly tried with double dot .. Thanks with triple dot it worked as expected ! thanks all.

Comment: In @user379997 's defense, the second hit brings up `p4 sync`.  Okay, that explains how to do it, but I could easily see someone saying, before reading the link, "well, I don't want to sync, I just want to see if things are up to date".  If someone is new to Perforce, they probably aren't familiar with the `-n` flag available to many commands.  Looking through `p4 sync` usage to find a "fake sync" wouldn't be my first instinct, I would look through other commands.

Comment: And doing a search with "finding whether the directories are latest in perforce" the same phrasing as the question here, doesn't produce anything that would stand out to me (other than this very page of course).

Comment: @Chance Surprise, reading comprehension *still* required to be a programmer; it's not sufficient to just type your questions into Google and have it provide *all* the answers ;-)  With SO we are getting awfully close though ;-)